# cannot use multiple doc.html() for the same document

Tags: javascript, jspdf

To my understanding after going through GitHub, documentation and stack overflow:

1. doc.html() is supposed to be able to take in a string with html formatting (AKA rich text)
2. There has been work done to ensure that doc.html() is able to produce multiple html snippets within the same pdf document
3. To produce more than one html in the same document, one is supposed to utilize the callback function and nest any further edits to the pdf.
4. doc.html() does not behave in the same sense as the other functions (text, rect, etc.) where you can add as many as you want.

```js
var pageWidth = 1000,
  lineHeight = 1,
  margin = 20,
  maxLineWidth = pageWidth - margin * 2,
  fontSize = 11,
  ptsPerMM = 72 / 25.6,
  oneLineHeight = (fontSize * lineHeight) / ptsPerMM;

var doc = new jspdf.jsPDF({
  orientation: 'p',
  unit: 'pt',
  format: 'letter',
  lineHeight: lineHeight
});


var field1 = "<b>this is field 1 </b>";
var field2 = "<b>this is field 2 </b>";

//add first html
doc.html("<body>" + field1 + "</body>", {
  callback: function (doc) {
    //do nothing
  },
  width: maxLineWidth ,
  windowWidth: maxLineWidth , 
      html2canvas: {
          backgroundColor: 'lightyellow',
          width: maxLineWidth , 
          height: 150
      },
      backgroundColor: 'lightblue', 
    x: 10,
  y: 10,
  autoPaging: 'text'
});


//add second html
doc.html("<body>" + field2 + "</body>", {
  callback: function (doc) {
    //do nothing
  },
  width: maxLineWidth ,
  windowWidth: maxLineWidth , 
      html2canvas: {
          backgroundColor: 'lightyellow',
          width: maxLineWidth , 
          height: 150
      },
      backgroundColor: 'lightblue', 
    x: 10,
  y: 10,
  autoPaging: 'text'
});

//export pdf
window.open(doc.output('bloburl'));
```

The code above does not work. how can I fix this issue where I cannot export multiple html snippets in the same pdf document?

I went over GitHub, documentation and stack overflow and for the first time ever, whenever someone asks a question related to this topic, they don't seem to get an answer.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me figure this out.

I've tried returning doc within the callback and reusing that but that didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

just use `await` and make sure to `return doc` inside the callback

something like this

```js
var doc = new jspdf.jsPDF({
  orientation: 'p',
  unit: 'pt',
  format: 'letter'
});


var field = "<b>html test </b>";
doc.text(10, 10, "test");
//add first html
await doc.html(field, {
  callback: function (doc) {
    return doc;
  },
  width: 210,
  windowWidth: 210, 
      html2canvas: {
          backgroundColor: 'lightyellow',
          width: 210, 
          height: 150
      },
      backgroundColor: 'lightblue', 
  x: 10,
  y: 50,
  autoPaging: 'text'
});
window.open(doc.output('bloburl'));
```